# Probability and Statistics random independent variables

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

I can't figure out how to determine if these variables are independent. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Random variables x and y are described by the PDF:

$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
  k,& \text{if } x + y ≤ 1, x > 0, \text{ and } y > 0,\\
   0, & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$

Are $x$ and $y$ random independent variables?

Answer (score 3):

No.  For continuous random variables to be independent you have to be able to factor their joint density as $f(x,y)=f(x)f(y)$ for all values of $x,y$.  In your case you already know that if $x>0.7$ then $y$ must be less than $0.3$.